# How to change the "next disk" image in InnoSetup?

Tags: inno-setup

Is it possible to change the image on the "Setup Needs the Next Disk" dialog and how to do it?

[image: Screenshot of the "Setup Needs the Next Disk" dialog]

The image looks quite outdated with that floppy disk so I want to replace it.
I know how to insert/replace images on wizard pages (e.g. using `TBitmapImage.Create(WizardForm)`) but I can't find any reference to that dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That dialog loads this ancient image [`from the resource`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/master/Projects/NewDisk.pas#L89) and you'll get [`no reference`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/master/Projects/NewDisk.pas#L55) to that dialog, so the only option I can think of is modifying the `DISKIMAGE` resource bitmap in the Setup.e32 binary template file with some resource editor tool.

Comment: Setup.e32 you can find in your Inno Setup directory.

Comment: Can you guide me a bit in the right direction to edit this Setup.e32 file?
What type of file is this? Where does it come from (is it something specific to Delphi/the visual component library)? Or ideally: do you know any such "resource editor tool"?

Comment: Nevermind! I just found the [line in compile.bat](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/5203240a7de9b83c5432bee0b5b09d467869a02b/compile.bat#L73) which "creates" the Setup.e32: it's just a normal Windows executable. So I will try a tool called [ResourceHacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/).